# android : No resource identifier found for attribute 'animateLayoutChanges' in package 'android'

Tags: android, animation

which android package has animateLayoutChanges attribute. 
i tried with 2.3 ,4.1 etc but still getting same error

Comment: If you are building with Eclipse, make sure your project's build target is set to Honeycomb too. @preetha

Comment: i tried setting project buid target as 3.2 as well, which is honeycomb . Is there any where else i need to change

Comment: a clean build solved issue. Thank you

Comment: ohh nice then write you own answer :p

Answer (score 0):

this feature are only supported after the android 3.0, as this is the property animation.
if you want to use this feature, you have to change the android:minSdkVersion="11",
if this does not work, right click on the project name, choose the "Properties" items, then 
make the build target as API level 11, that is android 3.0, apply and save this configuration, then the animateLayoutChange could be use.

by the way, if you want to adopt the android animation that only provided by the android 3.0 or upper version on the old android version, you could try nineOldAndroid project, it has implement the animation for the old android version.